# UIStepper swallows the touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uistepper

I'm using an `UIStepper` to change a value that is displayed in a `UITextField`, with the option of being editable entering the value in the `UITextField`.

Everything works fine, but there is a undesired behavior: the `UITextField` can only be edited pressing the upper half of the object itself, because the touch in the lower half is swallowed by the `UIStepper`.

I've looking for an answer, but I haven't find any. I have some hint though.

`UIStepper` has 2 buttons and 1 `ImageView`, and the touch is detected in the entire `ImageView` (not visible or editable).

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this would most likely require subclassing.  You can override [`pointInside:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside%3awithEvent%3a) in a `UIStepper` subclass and return `NO` unless strictly within the bounds of the stepper:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put both the stepper and the text field inside a container view that overrides `-hitTest:withEvent:` such that it queries the text field before querying the stepper. If the text field says that it's hit, return a pointer to the text field. If not, check the stepper and return that if it says it's hit.

Controls sometimes pretend to be larger than they are so that they're easier to touch. Using the preceding technique should let you keep as much of the stepper's extra touchable area as possible without hindering use of the text view.